# What does double-check mean in four-player chess on chess.com?

Tags: chess-variants, check

The rule says:
**Delivering a double-check is worth +5, and triple-checks are worth +15**

Is a double check when I am

- checking two players at one move
- checking one player with a normal double check
- checking a player that is already under check

Counting that there is a "triple check" either the rule one or three should be true because you can not give a triple check to one player by only your move. However, I am not sure if there are points for the normal double-check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double Check in 4 man chess basically means  checking  two kings in one move.
Same goes for triple check.

PS. It's not worth the points so don't go for it unless you win because of it.

Comment: But what if I will deliver a double check to one King? Or deliver a double check to one King and a Normal check to another in one Move?

Comment: Depends on number of Kings you check. So double check as in normal chess ie. to one king is not possible

Answer (score 4):

### Double Check

As @A.Shetye has pointed out, Double check means checking two kings at once in your single move.

More discussion on the topic is mentioned in this chess.com post - [Double and triple checks 4pc](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/chess960-chess-variants/weird-double-and-triple-checks-in-4-player-check)

### Double Checkmate

Well, in fact, in 4-player chess, you can even "Double Checkmate" your opponents. Have a look at a recent game I've played. I've checkmated both the kings at once xD

[image: Double checkmating - 4 Player Chess]

Here's the game link - https://www.chess.com/variants/4-player-chess/game/31704333/154/4

Comment: They should award a GM norm for that